# Android - REST API post, What do i need in my header

Tags: android, api, rest, cookies, drupal

I have an Android application which should post data to my Drupal site, via REST API.
I have a login. 
From this login, i can get the session name, session id and token.

My Question.
How do you make a post after login.
Do i need to add the session id, session name and token to the header?
Should i also add the username and password to the header when i make a post.
What about cookies? (Does session id and session name make the cookie?)
How do you add the cookie to the header.

This is what i have so far. 
onPostExecute, I get this message from result
**Node Type is required**

I have been struggling with this for a long time.
If you have any suggestions or know of any good examples / tutorials please let me know.

Thanks in advance

```
public String session_name;
public String session_id;
public String token;

private class JsonPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String address = "http://app.flickgo.com/apistuff/node.json";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        CookieManager cookies = new CookieManager();
        cookies.getCookieStore().add(null, new HttpCookie("app.flickgo.com", "/"));
        cookies.getCookieStore().add(null, new HttpCookie("has_js", "1"));
        cookies.getCookieStore().add(null, new HttpCookie(session_name, session_id));

        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String userCredentials = "my_username:my_password";
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-CSRF-Token", token);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));

            String title = "Mobile";
            String body = "Mobile body";
            String input = ("{ \"title\":\""+title+"\",\"type\":\"article\",\"body\":{\"und\":[{ \"value\":\""+body+"\"}]}}");

            writer.write(input);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            InputStream inputStream;
            // get stream
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            }
            // parse stream
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String temp, response = "";
            while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += temp;
            }
            // put into JSONObject
            jsonObject.put("Content", response);
            jsonObject.put("Message", urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            jsonObject.put("Length", urlConnection.getContentLength());
            jsonObject.put("Type", urlConnection.getContentType());

            return jsonObject.toString();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you exactly know what your REST API want ? so that we can figure out.

Comment: I have tested it on Postman. I would login with username and password. Get the token and add it to postman (X-CSRF-Token). I was able to post to Drupal from Postman. Do i only need the toke? Do i have to add username and password again to post data, when i already have the token?

Comment: if so, in the above code i dnt see any token assign. it should be null in the above code. 
If u got success with postman, you can get from code as well. suggest u to check the token value in code.

Comment: also, u had `cookies` object in u r code. i dnt used it anywhere. check it once. post updated code here.

Comment: Not sure how to add the cookie to the urlConnection without getting an error

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
This is how i added the cookie.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",session_name+"="+session_id);
```